# Margin 0 auto to a span within div not working

Tags: html, css, center, margin

I'd call a span within a div, its taking margins but margin:0 auto is not working. Any suggestion?

**html**

```
<div>
    <span>
         <h3>Paris Eurostar Breaks</h3>
         <p>Curabitur fringilla mauris interdum nec magna</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
div{
    width:465px;
    min-height:201px;
}
div span{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px #FFF solid;
    border-top:1px #FFF solid;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
```

**Output Required**

[image]

Comment: Would the center html tag do what you're needing?

Comment: I'm confused why you would use a span and not a div in your situation. I've never used a span for anything other than selecting parts of inline-elements.

Comment: Note your html is invalid: the content model for [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) elements is [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1), but [`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) and [`h3`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) can only be used where [flow content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To center `horizontal` with `margin` the element must have a fixed `width`.

Since you are using `inline-block` Try this:

```
div {
  text-align:Center;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`margin: 0 auto` will center horizontally block-level elements, but not inline-block ones:

> [**10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth)
>
> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values
>   are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the
>   edges of the containing block.
>
> [**10.3.9 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)
>
> A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes
>   a used value of '0'.

To center an `inline-block`, you can add `text-align: center` to its container.

```css
div{
  width:465px;
  min-height:201px;
  text-align: center;
}
div span{
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  border-top:1px solid;
  margin:0 auto;  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>
         <h3>Paris Eurostar Breaks</h3>
         <p>Curabitur fringilla mauris interdum nec magna</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `display` to `block` and then add a width to your span. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yu2Lucvx/)